# bookdown new project in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, bookdown

The issue similar to the one reported here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2055. But I don't see a solution anywhere.

I am trying to start a new bookdown project in Rstudio.
I have compiled the bookdown project from Github to get the latest version.

```
> sessionInfo(package = "bookdown")
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] bookdown_0.7.18

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.4  graphics_3.4.4  tools_3.4.4     utils_3.4.4     yaml_2.2.0      grDevices_3.4.4
 [7] stats_3.4.4     datasets_3.4.4  knitr_1.20      methods_3.4.4   xfun_0.3        base_3.4.4     
[13] fortunes_1.5-4
```

I try to start a new project in Rstudio and it gives the following error:
a pop up with "R code execution error"

and then the  error:

```
Error in gsub(pattern, val, transformed, ignore.case = TRUE) : 
  invalid regular expression '\$options(digits\b', reason 'Missing ')''
```

Could anyone tell what could be the issue here?